# save username but shows name in c#

Tags: c#, session, session-variables

I'm working with c#, in vs 2008, framework 3.5, I need to save the username and when
  the   user log in, it shows he/her first and last name, at this point can save it, and
  that is what I want but need to show to the user not his/her username just the first and
  last name. here is my code, thanks in advance.

```
//code in the login
ClPersona login = new ClPersona();
bool isAuthenticated = login.sqlLogin1((txtUsuario.Text), (txtPassword.Text));
if (isAuthenticated)
{
Session["sesionicontrol"] = login.NombreUsuario;
Response.Redirect("../MENU/menu1.aspx");
}

//code in the form where shows the username but I want the first and last name

public partial class menu2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
lblNombreUsuario.Text = (string)Session["sesionicontrol"]; 
if (!IsPostBack)


//ClPersona class

public Boolean sqlLogin1(string nombreUsuario, string password)
{
string stSql = "select * from usuarios where usuario='" + nombreUsuario + "' and
pass='" + password + "'and id_rol='1'";
Bd miBd = new Bd();
DataTable dt = miBd.sqlSelect(stSql);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
//return ds;
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Does the `login` object provide access to properties for retrieving the first name and last name that can be stored in the session?

Comment: @mellamokb no, the problem is that I need to save the username in my database, but the user must see he/her first name and last name not he/her username, thanks in advance

Comment: Please show sqlLogin1 method and ClPersona class

Answer (score 0):

Modify two sections

First

```
if (isAuthenticated)
{
Session["YouObject"] = login;//<--

Session["sesionicontrol"] = login.NombreUsuario;
Response.Redirect("../MENU/menu1.aspx");
}
```

Second

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(Session["YouObject"] != null)
   { 
     ClPersona obj = (ClPersona )Session["YouObject"];
     lblNombreUsuario.Text = string.Format("{0}-{1}", obj.FirstName, obj.LastName ) 


   }

      lblNombreUsuario.Text = (string)Session["sesionicontrol"];
     ....
}
```